# Spawn children command and listen to the output

Tags: rust, tauri

am new in tauri and I couldn't find the solution.

I want to call a command from my package.js of another project.

Lets say `'npm run dev'` script in the `package.json` runs `'nodemon --config nodemon.json src/app.ts'`.

I want the command to run and then listen to all the output, every line, until it is killed.

I don't want new window terminals to be spawned, I want the commands to run in the background.

The ideal solution for me, is to create threads of each command I run, and each thread returns in real time the output of each command.

Thanks in advance.

I manage to create a new command with

```
let (mut rx, mut child) = Command::new("node")
    .spawn()
    .expect("Failed to spawn node");
```

and then kill it with

```
child.kill();
```

but that's all I manage to do.

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation i manage to call the command and print the output but after that the window of the tauri app stop responding so i need to close it.
Here is the code i tried.

```rs
use std::process;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::thread;
use process::Stdio;
use process::Command;
use std::io::BufRead;

fn main() {
    let mut program_path = "node";
  let mut child = Command::new(program_path)
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .stderr(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .unwrap();

    let child_stdout = child
        .stdout
        .take()
        .expect("Internal error, could not take stdout");
    let child_stderr = child
        .stderr
        .take()
        .expect("Internal error, could not take stderr");

    let (stdout_tx, stdout_rx) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();
    let (stderr_tx, stderr_rx) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();

    let stdout_thread = thread::spawn(move || {
        let stdout_lines = BufReader::new(child_stdout).lines();
        for line in stdout_lines {
            let line = line.unwrap();
            println!("{}", line);
            stdout_tx.send(line).unwrap();
        }
    });

    let stderr_thread = thread::spawn(move || {
        let stderr_lines = BufReader::new(child_stderr).lines();
        for line in stderr_lines {
            let line = line.unwrap();
            println!("{}", line);
            stderr_tx.send(line).unwrap();
        }
    });

    let status = child
        .wait()
        .expect("Internal error, failed to wait on child");

    stdout_thread.join().unwrap();
    stderr_thread.join().unwrap();

    let stdout = stdout_rx.into_iter().collect::<Vec<String>>().join("");
    let stderr = stderr_rx.into_iter().collect::<Vec<String>>().join("");
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks @Pate, was very useful. I added the required libs to your code.